# Live TV in Google TV emulation

Tags: google-tv

According to the developer site documentation, Google TV emulation supports live tv. Local provider list will be obtained by giving zip code of the area.

Does this work with an Indian Zip code? If yes, will the ChannelListing information of the provider be accessible free of cost or does it impose any subscription charges?

How does this actually work?

Comment: **I do not know if this is how it actually works.** But in the US (at least), there are channel identifiers broadcast as part of the digital signal. The device could easily just be reading those. The ZIP code would probably only be required for things like cable TV services… If that's the case, there's really no reason that any other countries using the US broadcast standard (ATSC) wouldn't also work “out of the box…” (and if they *don't* do it that way, ***why‽***)

Answer (score 0):

It only works for US zip codes at present.  There is no charge.

Comment: It would be nice to see this in the EU as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found that at least the GoogleTV I got also has only US zip-codes for location and no ability to select non-US locations not other languages but english.